# Uploaded file name save in database when return from paypal successfully

Tags: php, paypal, transactions, paypal-sandbox

I have a form through which cart data is processed and onclick button it processes with paypal. I have made a `success.php` page which will be auto return when transaction will be completed. All the fields are successfully saving in db but i am stuck with the file which a user will upload. My question is, Is there any way to save uploaded file name in database when paypal checkout returns successfully to the `success.php` page and if so, Then how can i pass the variable within paypal button? I have go through many searches regarding this. But none helped my issue. Any suggestions or guide will be appreciated. 
**form.php**

```
     <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
   <input type="hidden" name="business" value="sriniv_1293527277_biz@inbox.com">
   <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
   <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
    <input type="file" name="custom" >
     <Label> Select shipment interval (optional):
     <select id="shipment_option" name="shipment">
      <option  selected="selected" value="7" id="7">7</option>
      <option value="6" id="6"> 6 </option>
       <option value="5" id="5">5 </option>
        </select></Label>
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="success.php">
     <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="paypal_cancel.php">
    <input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="LG.gif">
    </form>
```

**success.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include("db/db.php");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
?>
<html>
<title>Success</title>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['cart']) && isset ($_SESSION['login_email'])){
$total=0;
$email=$_SESSION['login_email'];
$ships=$_POST['shipment'];
$file=$_FILES['file']['custom'];//this is how i am  trying to get the file name. But it doesnot work

//customer information
$query1=mysqli_query($con,"select * from customers where email='$email'");
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($query1,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
$user=$rows['name'];
$user_id=$rows['serial'];
}

 //orders and order details.
$que=mysqli_query($con,"insert into orders(custom_file,date,customerid,status,ship_days) values('$file',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),'$user_id','confirmed','$ships')");
if($que)
{
$m=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['name'],'./ServerUploadedFiles/'.$user.$file);

$q=mysqli_query($con,"select serial from orders where customerid='$user_id' and date=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()");
while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($q,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
$order_id=$row1['serial'];

}
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value){

$subtotal=$value['price']*$value['quantity'];
$pid=$value['id'];
$quantity=$value['quantity'];
$color=$value['color'];
$size=$value['size'];
$total+= $subtotal;

$query= mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO order_detail(orderid,productid,quantity,price,color,size) VALUES ($order_id, $pid, $quantity, $subtotal, '$color', '$size')");

}


}
//payment details for paypal
    $amount=$_GET['amt'];
    $currency=$_GET['cc'];
    $trx_id=$_GET['tx'];
    $insert_payments= mysqli_query($con,"insert into payments(amount,cust_id,order_id,trx_id,currency) values('$amount','$user_id','$order_id','$trx_id','$currency')");

    if($amount==$total)
    {
       unset($_SESSION['cart']);
       echo "<h2>Hello". $user."You have successfully done purchasing process.Please <a href='profile.php'>Go to your account</a>!</h2>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<h2>Hello". $user."Your payment was not successful.Please <a href='profile.php'>Go to your account</a>!</h2>";
    }
   }
?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PayPal's "[custom](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HH00W2J)" variable to pass this over to PayPal, and it will also be returned to you in the post back to your site.  Buyer's also wont see this variable on their end.

Comment: okay i tried what you mentioned. But i am confused how to get the custom value? I am updating my code have a look please.

Comment: plus i want same for the shipment dropdown. How to pass its value to custom as well